# Create Two Column Bulleted List

Tags: html

How can I create a 2 column bulleted list in `HTML`?  I know that I can use to create a bulleted list, but how can I create that seperate column directly beside it to have a completely different bulleted list?

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way it to embed it in a table:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
            <li>First</li>
            <li>List</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
            <li>Second</li>
            <li>List</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hpkqxhsr/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is to put each ul inside a div and then float the divs.
Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/Ot1VwmETyXO5iJeCevTm?p=preview

```
<div style="float:left;">
<ul>
<li>One</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div style="float:left;">
<ul>
<li>Two</li>
</ul>
</div>
```